# How do I convert my program to use C++ namespaces?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, namespaces

My code was working fine, until I tried to wrap all of my class definitions in a namespace.

```
// "Player.h"
#include "PhysicsObject.h"
namespace MaelstromII
{
    class Player : public MaelstromII::PhysicsObject
    {
        // ...
    };
}

// "PhysicsObject.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
namespace MaelstromII
{
    class PhysicsObject : public MaelstromII::GameObject
    {
        // ...
    };
}

// "GameObject.h"
namespace MaelstromII
{
    class GameObject
    {
        // ...
    };
}
```

When I compile in Visual Studio, I get a bunch of these errors:

> error C2039: 'PhysicsObject' : is not a member of 'MaelstromII'

It complains about `GameObject`, too.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: When you're already inside the same namespace, you can just do `public PhysicsObject` instead of `public MaelstromII::PhysicsObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the trouble was caused by a circular dependency in my code somewhere else. After fixing that problem, my code compiled fine.

Evidently, there is no difference between this:

```
namespace Foo {
    class Bar {}
    class Bar2 : public Bar {}
}
```

And this:

```
namespace Foo {
    class Bar {}
    class Bar2 : public Foo::Bar {}
}
```

The compiler resolves them the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100%, but I think what's going on when you say

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Bar : public Foo::BarBase {}
}
```

is the same as:

```
class Foo::Bar : public Foo::Foo::BarBase {}
```

When you're in a namespace, you don't need to use the namespace:: specifier to access other things in that namespace.

Comment: True, but it's not going to cause an error either since it will keep going up the namespace hierarchy looking for `Foo::BarBase` and will find it relative to the top-level nemaspace.

Comment: Aha? Learn something new every day. Thanks!